# How to set datagrip to take same timezone as the host database

Tags: database, datagrip, intellij-datagrip

I want that my postgres datagrip connection should take the same timezone as the remote source (host) its connected to. How do I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need the time zone setting in the properties of the connection.

[image]

Comment: I have encounter requirements and there exist several table with different timezone, could you please the config detail?

Comment: It is not super clear, but I hope here must be the needed info: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2996

Comment: And, need a re-connection to take effect.